# Support for putting Quartz Jobs ON_ICE and ON_HOLD like autosys

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, scheduling

Hi use Quartz to trigger some trivial cronTrigger based timer jobs which dont do much.
I wish to support putting these jobs ON_ICE and ON_HOLD just like autosys.

for context:

1. ON_ICE -> if a job is put on_ice and taken off_ice and the condition had passed in the past it is ignored and the job is triggered only for its next trigger.
2. ON_HOLD -> if a job is put on_hold and taken off_hold and the condition had passed in the past it is fired immediately and the job continues its normal execution as per next schedules.

The way this can be achieved is using the pauseJob() and resumeJob() functions for a job

I use the misFireInstruction -> **fireAndProceed** by default since I want other normal jobs to follow that policy.

but in case a job is put ON_ICE and taken off_ice its misFire instruction should behave like **doNothing**

I could not update the misFireInstruction of the cronTrigger during runTime directly I had to unschedule the job and reschedule it with new misFireInstruction everytime a job was put ON_ICE.

Is there a better way to do it?

below is the code:

QuartzTimer.java

```
    package org.example;
    
    import org.quartz.*;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class QuartzTimer {
        private Scheduler scheduler;
    
        public QuartzTimer() throws SchedulerException {
            this.scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        }
    
        public void submitJob(String jobName, String cronSchedule) throws SchedulerException {
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(jobName+"Trigger")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronSchedule)
                    //everyJobNeedsToFireOnceAndProceedInCaseOfMisfires        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                    .forJob(jobName)
                    .build();
    
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(TimerJob.class).withIdentity(jobName).build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
        }
    
        public void suspendJob(String jobName, boolean isOnIce) throws SchedulerException {
            scheduler.pauseJob(JobKey.jobKey(jobName));
            if(isOnIce) {
/*if Job is supposed to be put ON_ICE then its misFires should be ignored*/
                updateMisfireInstructionForJob(jobName, CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING);
            }
        }
    
        public void resumeJob(String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
            scheduler.resumeJob(JobKey.jobKey(jobName));
/*incase job is taken off_ice or off_hold make sure to revert misfireinstruction*/
            updateMisfireInstructionForJob(jobName, updateMisfireInstructionForJob(jobName, CronTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW);
        }
    
        public void updateMisfireInstructionForJob(String jobName, int misFireCode) throws SchedulerException {
            final JobKey jobKey = JobKey.jobKey(jobName);
            List<? extends Trigger> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
            triggers.forEach(trigger -> {
                if(trigger instanceof CronTriggerImpl) {
                    CronTriggerImpl cronTrigger = (CronTriggerImpl) trigger;
                    if(cronTrigger.getMisfireInstruction() == misFireCode) {
                        return;
                    }
                    cronTrigger.setMisfireInstruction(misFireCode);
                    try {
                        JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey);
                        scheduler.unscheduleJob(cronTrigger.getKey());
                        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
                    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
    
    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

TimerJob.java

```
package org.example;

import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TimerJob implements Job {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimerJob.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.info("Executing job: {}", context.getJobDetail().getKey());
        LOGGER.info("ScheduledTime: {} fireTime: {}", context.getScheduledFireTime(), context.getFireTime());
        LOGGER.info("prevFireTime: {} nextFireTime: {}", context.getPreviousFireTime(), context.getNextFireTime());
    }
}
```

I know that instead of unscheduling and rescheduling with change misFireinstruction trigger causes loss of trigger history in it with the firetimes etc.

somehow if I knew that a particular job execution is a misFire I could just ignore it in case the job was on_ice and was taken off_ice.

also is there a way to update the JobDataMap of a jobDetail once a job is scheduled?